# Discord Bot won't start due to logic error

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I'm making this bot (i'm fairly new to javascript) and for no reason, it doesn't say anything after i type `node .` and then it shuts down. I suspect it has something to do with my console.log, but i checked, and that all seems to be in order i don't know how to fix this

```
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'TOKEN';

const prefix = "!"

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot online')

    bot.on('message', msg => {
        if (msg.content === "hello")
                msg.reply('hewo');
        }
    )

    bot.on('message', msg => {

    let args = msg.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'summon':
            msg.channel('hi')
        break;
    }
});
        bot.login(token)
})

return;

`
```

Comment: You may remove the return statement at the end of the file.

Comment: Which Discord library are you using?

Comment: Following up on @JackRed, you should move your token to a config file and put it in your `.gitignore` so you don't commit it to a github repo. There are web crawlers that specifically look for discord tokens in public repos and hijack the bots.

Answer (score 1):

- Move the `bot.login(token)` outside the ready event, as it will only
  be run after bot.login().
- Same goes for the messages events, while
  they can be inside the ready event, they shouldn't!
- The return is
  useless there, remove it.

In the end it should look like:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'TOKEN';

const prefix = '!';

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot online');
});

bot.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === 'hello') {
        msg.reply('hewo');
    }
});

bot.on('message', msg => {
    const args = msg.content.substring(prefix.length).split(' ');

    switch(args[0]) {
    case 'summon':
        msg.channel('hi');
        break;
    }
});

bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const Bot_Token= require('./config.json')

const prefix = "!"
bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot online')
})
    bot.on('message', msg => {
        if (msg.content === "hello")
                msg.reply('hewo');
        }
    )

    bot.on('message', msg => {

    let args = msg.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'summon':
            msg.channel('hi')
        break;
    }
});
        bot.login(token)
```

First of all you need to declare `Discord`, and you don't need the return statment at the end.
For better security make an config.json, where you will have the token `{"Bot_Token" = "Token"}`.